# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0- Java Adapter fails to execute on the server side

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm getting the following on my MobileFirst Java Adapter when performing an addition
`Error 500: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

```
@Path("/calc")
public class Calculator {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    //Define the server api to be able to perform server operations
    WLServerAPI api = WLServerAPIProvider.getWLServerAPI();
    @GET
    @Path("/addTwoIntegers/{first}/{second}")
    public int addTwoIntegers(@PathParam("first") String first, @PathParam("second") String second){
        int a=Integer.parseInt(first);
        int b=Integer.parseInt(second);
        int c=a+b;
       return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am removing quotations it throws an error like,                        Multiple markers at this line
 - first cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - second cannot be resolved to a 
  variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the return type of your adapter. Since you are returning an `int` it is trying to convert it to a `string` and that's when it's failing hence the `Error 500: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Try updating your code as follow:

```
@Path("/calc")
public class Calculator {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    //Define the server api to be able to perform server operations
    WLServerAPI api = WLServerAPIProvider.getWLServerAPI();
    @GET
    @Path("/addTwoIntegers/{first}/{second}")
    public String addTwoIntegers(@PathParam("first") String first, @PathParam("second") String second){
        int a=Integer.parseInt(first);
        int b=Integer.parseInt(second);
        int c=a+b;
       return Integer.toString(c);
    }
}
```